# Is 那 often used as a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, characters, simplified-characters

Still forwarding on my lexicon, i am wondering about the use of 那 as a conjunction meaning " then, in that case ".
Is it really often used in that usage in modern Chinese ?
There are other Chinese characters for " then, in that case ", like 便, 就, 㕢...
,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 那 and 就 are very commonly used in daily conversations.

For example,

- 要是你沒空，那我找別人陪我去。
- 要是你沒空，我就找別人陪我去。
- 要是你沒空，那我就找別人陪我去。
- 遇到紅燈，就得停下來。
- 你不同意，那就算了。
- 這就對了。

便 is usually used in formal writing. I seldom hear people say this word as a conjunction.

I'm not sure if you want to say 㕢 or 爾. I haven't seen the word 㕢 before.